# Нужно вытащить данные в формате xml из столбца clob в туже таблицу

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица oracle с разными данными и в нем есть столбец clob, где хранятся данные в формате xml, мне нужно вывести все данные из xml в таблицу.

пример xml файла:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <Header>
    <MessageInfo>
      <To>DDDDD</To>
      <From>DDDDD</From>
      <MessageID>DDDDDD-DDD-00293190</MessageID>
      <MessageType>DDD_DDDDDDDD_DETAILS</MessageType>
      <Priority>5</Priority>
      <CreationTime>2028-08-18T02:16:17</CreationTime>
    </MessageInfo>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <CommonInfo>
      <BankPartner>
        <BIK>ADADADADA</BIK>
      </BankPartner>
      <PaymentReference>DDDDDD-DDD-00293190</PaymentReference>
      <CommonSumm>11111111</CommonSumm>
    </CommonInfo>
    <LoansList>
      <Loan>
        <Num>1</Num>
        <LoanCodeBank>1111;88888888</LoanCodeBank>
        <PaymentsList>
          <PaymentDetails>
            <Num>1</Num>
            <PaymentDate>2028-08-17</PaymentDate>
            <PaymentKind>002</PaymentKind>
            <Summ>11111.33</Summ>
          </PaymentDetails>
          <PaymentDetails>
            <Num>2</Num>
            <PaymentDate>2028-08-17</PaymentDate>
            <PaymentKind>001</PaymentKind>
            <Summ>44444.55</Summ>
          </PaymentDetails>
        </PaymentsList>
      </Loan>
    </LoansList>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: В студию - структуру таблицы (CREATE TABLE) с минимально нужными полями, пример данных (INSERT INTO), требуемое финальное состояние данных (таблицей). И да, весь длинный XML не обязателен, достаточно минимального...

Comment: xml-парсер человеку нужен, так-то сам раскидает потом данные. "каким языком владеете?". и на яве и на питоне возможности есть. вам нужны xpath для полей?

Comment: я знаю немного только sql, если поможете с парсером xml то остальные столбцы дума добавлю (там их много просто, по этому не стал описывать структуру основной таблицы).

Comment: Да в Оракле целая пачка функций для работы с XML. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF56667 Комбинируя их, можно сделать всё, что угодно - разве что за пивом бегать не могут... тебе так и вовсе просто на основе схемы использовать несколько вложенных XMLTABLE - и они разберут весь твой XML на связанные поля.

Comment: там не все так просто, вот пример, ищете "python xml xpath", много читаете, потом ищете xpath 1.0 cheat sheet, курите-пробуете. самое главное для вас понять и применить xpath, остальное совсем просто. ну и @Akina правильно сказал. что у Оракла тоже есть возможности. счас поищем - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E96926_01/WXML/Content/using-xpath.htm

Comment: @nexoma А какой такой великий смысл тянуть по одному значению, когда можно сразу весь XML развернуть в одну plain-таблицу? вот ей-ей, быстрее будет. Да и по ресурсам дешевше.

Comment: @Akina. увы ушел из оракла не познав сего, посему не могу ничего сказать. ну и вопрос к задающему, а он-то знает? есть у него эти оракловые талмуды? да и тяжела всегда была у них документация.